# MUI 5 + HeadlessUI: Can't close <DatePicker /> inside <Dialog />

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I'm using HeadlessUI in combination with MUI 5 and facing an issue where i can't close the `<DatePicker />` date selection popper when using it inside a `<Dialog />` component from HeadlessUI. The popper should close when i click anywhere outside the popper but inside the modal.

I tried using MUI's `<ClickAwayListener />` and also setting the popper to be rendered within the `<Dialog />` by using `PopperProps={{ disablePortal: true }}` but both without success. Maybe i'm missing something obvious?

```js
import { Dialog, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";
import DatePicker from "@mui/lab/DatePicker";

export default function MyModal() {
  let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  function closeModal() {
    setIsOpen(false);
  }

  function openModal() {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center">
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={openModal}
          className="px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-black rounded-md bg-opacity-20 hover:bg-opacity-30 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-opacity-75"
        >
          Open dialog
        </button>
      </div>

      <Transition appear show={isOpen} as={Fragment}>
        <Dialog
          as="div"
          className="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto"
          onClose={() => {}}
        >
          <div className="min-h-screen px-4 text-center">
            <Transition.Child
              as={Fragment}
              enter="ease-out duration-300"
              enterFrom="opacity-0"
              enterTo="opacity-100"
              leave="ease-in duration-200"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100"
              leaveTo="opacity-0"
            >
              <Dialog.Overlay className="fixed inset-0" />
            </Transition.Child>

            {/* This element is to trick the browser into centering the modal contents. */}
            <span
              className="inline-block h-screen align-middle"
              aria-hidden="true"
            >
              &#8203;
            </span>
            <Transition.Child
              as={Fragment}
              enter="ease-out duration-300"
              enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
              enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
              leave="ease-in duration-200"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
              leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
            >
              <div className="inline-block w-full max-w-md p-6 my-8 overflow-hidden text-left align-middle transition-all transform bg-white shadow-xl rounded-2xl">
                <Dialog.Title
                  as="h3"
                  className="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
                >
                  Payment successful
                </Dialog.Title>
                <div className="mt-2">
                  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                    <DatePicker
                      label="Basic example"
                      value={value}
                      onChange={(newValue) => {
                        setValue(newValue);
                      }}
                      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                    />
                  </LocalizationProvider>
                </div>

                <div className="mt-4">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="inline-flex justify-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-blue-900 bg-blue-100 border border-transparent rounded-md hover:bg-blue-200 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-offset-2 focus-visible:ring-blue-500"
                    onClick={closeModal}
                  >
                    Got it, thanks!
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Transition.Child>
          </div>
        </Dialog>
      </Transition>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit eloquent-clarke-fl8uc]

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into the same problem when using `@headlessui`'s Dialog, but then in a Slider Over manner.

I've replaced my `@headlessui` Dialog with a MUI Drawer instead and I can open and close the Datepicker without problem.

Taking your example, here's an example on how I've done this:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import DialogTitle from "@mui/material/DialogTitle";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";
import DatePicker from "@mui/lab/DatePicker";

export default function MyModal() {
  let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  function closeModal() {
    setIsOpen(false);
  }

  function openModal() {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center">
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={openModal}
          className="px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white bg-black rounded-md bg-opacity-20 hover:bg-opacity-30 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-opacity-75"
        >
          Open dialog
        </button>
      </div>

      <Dialog onClose={closeModal} open={isOpen}>
        <DialogTitle className="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">
          Payment successful
        </DialogTitle>
        <div className="p-6 my-8 overflow-hidden text-left align-middle bg-white w-96 h-96">
          <div className="mt-2">
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
              <DatePicker
                label="Basic example"
                value={value}
                onChange={(newValue) => {
                  setValue(newValue);
                }}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
              />
            </LocalizationProvider>
          </div>

          <div className="mt-4">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="inline-flex justify-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-blue-900 bg-blue-100 border border-transparent rounded-md"
              onClick={closeModal}
            >
              Got it, thanks!
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit crimson-water-o725uc]